# Change port for pootle server

Tags: python, django, cherrypy, pootle

I have just setup Pootle translation server, but as being absolute beginner with Python, and fact that I can't find any configuration setting in default file that Pootle installation creates regarding HTTP port that servers run on, hope that someone here can give me quick tip.

From Pootle's documentation:

> By default Pootle provides a built-in CherryPy server that will be
>   enough for quickly testing the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in [CherryPy server's default port is 8000](https://github.com/translate/pootle/blob/cb1b2fb967e220a04747c3ebc96b579796bbabca/pootle/apps/pootle_app/management/commands/__init__.py#L131), and you can change it by passing `--port <port-number>` to the `pootle start` command.

Note however you should only use CherryPy for testing, and [setting up a reverse proxy is highly recommended](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/stable-2.5.1/server/installation.html#running-pootle).

Answer (score 1):

In Pootle 2.7 you need to use:

`pootle run_cherrypy --port <PORT_NUM>`

instead of  `pootle start` which does not accept `--port` nor `--host`.

I need to have CherryPy bound to all interfaces, so I use:

`pootle run_cherrypy --host 0.0.0.0`

[Official documentation](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/stable-2.7.0/server/commands.html#run-cherrypy)